# Spring: ensure initialization order without 'depends-on'

Tags: java, spring

I have kinda complex spring context and I want to ensure that beans will be initialized in specific order.

```
-+ module 1
 ++ root-context.xml
  +- LocalSessionFactoryBean
-+ module 2
 ++ additional-context.xml
  +- MyHijackingBean
```

Before `module 1` was dependent on `module 2`. And `LocalSessionFactoryBean` was defined as:

```
<bean class="org.s.o.LocalSessionFactoryBean" depends-on="MyHijackingBean">
```

It was working great. `MyHijackingBean` was initialized with `@PostConstruct` before `LocalSessionFactoryBean` was created.

But now I have reversed dependency - `module 2` is dependent on `module 1`. So `module 1` doesn't know anything about `MyHijackingBean`

Can I somehow reverse `depends-on`? I've tried to use `BeanPostProcessor`, but there I don't have any possibility to control order of initalization.

Spring version - 3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` to add `depends-on` to the LocalSessionFactoryBean.